# C: Which character should be used for ptrdiff_t in printf?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

Which character should be used for `ptrdiff_t` in `printf`?

Does C standard clearly explains how to print `ptrdiff_t` in `printf`? I haven't found any one.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

int* pa = &a;
int* pb = &b;

ptrdiff_t diff = b - a;

printf("diff = %?", diff); // % what?
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's `%td`.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string).

Comment: That reference doesn't appear complete; the `t` character is a length modifier of the `d` type specifier.  I would also suggest you specify Visual Studio in your question if that is the platform you are interested in.

Comment: `%td` is standard. Visual Studio's C compiler doesn't conform to the current C standard.

Comment: @AmirSaniyan: The `t` is a size specifier, not a type (the type is `d` here).  [Apparently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx) `I` should be used as the size specifier for `ptrdiff_t` with the Microsoft implementation (so `%Id`), which is nonstandard.

Comment: @AmirSaniyan: **No.** `%td` is completely standard (§7.19.6.1, paragraph 7).  As Microsoft does not actually provide a C compiler, the behavior of VS has nothing to do with what is standard or not.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 supports both `%zu` and `%td` (not properly documented on MSDN, but both test out OK).

Answer (score 17):

C11 draft explains the length modifier for `ptrdiff_t` in 7.21.6.1 7 "The `fprintf` function"

> `t`
>   Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `ptrdiff_t` or the corresponding unsigned integer type argument; or that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `ptrdiff_t` argument.

Use `"%td"` as in the following: Credit: [@trojanfoe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7954455/2410359)

```
ptrdiff_t diff = b - a;
printf("diff = %td", diff);
```

---

If the compiler does **not support `"%td"`**, cast to a signed type - the longer, the better.  Then insure the alternative format and argument match.

```
// Note the cast
printf("diff = %lld", (long long) diff); // or
printf("diff = %ld", (long) diff);
```

Ref [format specifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders)

Answer (score 7):

Use `%td` and if your compiler does not support it, you should try `%ld` (also cast the input to `long`).