# Why does second printf print 0

Tags: c, pointers, output

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char arr[] = "somestring";
    char *ptr1 = arr;
    char *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;
    printf("ptr2 - ptr1 = %ld\n", ptr2 - ptr1);
    printf("(int*)ptr2 - (int*) ptr1 = %ld",  (int*)ptr2 - (int*)ptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand

```
 ptr2 - ptr1
```

gives 3 but cannot figure out why second printf prints 0.

Comment: Downvotes for asking a question?

Comment: Why do you cast to (int*)?

Comment: See: `(int*)ptr1 + 1` **>** `(int*)ptr2`

Comment: @Jerry , I did not. This is from some C quiz I was taking. I got this wrong.

Comment: Try Debug and check the values (watch)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, I am sorry. I did not understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @lan According to pointer mathematics when you add `1` then result will point to next location of same type Suppose `arr == 12` then `ptr1 == 12` and then `ptr1 + 3` == `15` and so `ptr2 == 15`. Now `ptr1` == `12` it you case to `int*` before adding `+` then `(int*)ptr1 + 1` = `16` for a system in which `sizeof (int*) == 4`.

Comment: Is this undefined behaviour (UB)?  Dereferencing `(int*)ptr1` would be, as it's not aligned properly (depending on platform).  But perhaps even the subtraction itself is UB with incorrectly-aligned pointers?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid, could be. But I tried on Mac,Windows and Linux. All gave the same answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because when you substract two pointers, you get the distance between the pointer in  number of elements, not in bytes.

```
(char*)ptr2-(char*)ptr1  // distance is 3*sizeof(char), ie 3
(int*)ptr2-(int*)ptr1  // distance is 0.75*sizeof(int), rounded to 0
```

EDIT: I was wrong by saying that the cast forces the pointer to be aligned

Comment: Sizeof int* on my machine is 8bytes. yet ptr2=ptr1+5 gives 1. So I am assuming even if size is 8bytes, it can align on 4 byte boundary. Am I right?

Comment: @IanMcGrath `sizeof(int)` is 4, not `sizeof(int*)`

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon, Now it makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, I went too fast.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check the distance between addresses don't use `(int *)` or `(void *)`, `ptrdiff_t` is a type able to represent the result of any valid pointer subtraction operation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(void)
{
    char arr[] = "somestring";
    char *ptr1 = arr;
    char *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;
    ptrdiff_t diff = ptr2 - ptr1;

    printf ("ptr2 - ptr1 = %td\n", diff);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by @chux, [use `"%td"` character for `ptrdiff_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7954439/1606345).

Comment: Did not know that. Have a +1, I accepted Benoit Blanchon's response because it explained me why it was 0. Still useful to know what you mentioned.

Comment: Per C11dr 6.5.6 9, the difference is type `ptrdiff_t`.  Thus casting the difference to type `(ptrdiff_t)` does not change anything.  To `printf()` this type, one should use `t` modifier as in `printf ("%td\n", ptr2 - ptr1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Casting a `char` pointer with `int*` would make it aligned to the 4bytes (considering int is 4 bytes here). Though `ptr1` and `ptr2` are 3 bytes away, casting them to `int*`, results in the same address -- hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `sizeof(int) == 4`

Each char takes 1 byte. Your array of chars looks like this in memory:

```
[s][o][m][e][s][t][r][i][n][g][0]
```

When you have an array of ints, each int occupies four bytes. storing '1' and '2' conceptually looks more like this:

```
[0][0][0][1][0][0][0][2]
```

Ints must therefore be aligned to 4-byte boundaries. Your compiler is aliasing the address to the lowest integer boundary. You'll note that if you use 4 instead of 3 this works as you expected.

The reason you have to perform a subtraction to get it to do it (just passing the casted pointers to printf doesn't do it) is because `printf` is not strictly typed, i.e. the `%ld` format does not contain the information that the parameter is an int pointer.