# Trying to understand pointer addition and subtraction but

Tags: c, pointers, long-integer

I don't know how to describe my problem, but here's the thing: I was trying to understand pointers better when reading K&R's book. I used their version of strlen() which used pointers, and that worked fine. Just to experiment with pointer arithmetic further, I wrote a really simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[10];
    char *sp;

    sp = s;

    printf("%d\n", (sp+7) - s);
    return 0;
}
```

It functioned correctly, but I don't understand the why this warning occurs:

```
hello3.c:10:17: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 
      'long' [-Wformat]
        printf("%d\n", (sp+7) - s);
                ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~
                %ld
```

I understand what the error is, but I don't know why this happens. How did that expression became a long type?

Comment: Don't use screenshots; copy-and-paste the text into your program. The code in your question doesn't produce that warning; the code in the screenshot does. Show us the code that produces the warning and the warning itself *in the question*.

Comment: pointers are `long` type (e.g. 32bit). But you're telling C to print them as an int (`%d`), which is a 16bit data type. `0x12340001` and `0x98760001` would both theoretically print out `0x0001` and appear identical, even though they're completely different values.

Comment: @MarcB: No, pointers are not "`long` type".  Pointers are pointers. The result of subtracting two pointers is of type `ptrdiff_t`, a typedef defined in `<stddef.h>` and corresponding to some implementation-defined signed integer type. `int` is *at least* 16 buts, but is commonly wider. But since the code that produces the error is not in the question, I suggest we hold off on answering it.

Comment: The warning showed in the screenshot is on a piece of code that does not appear in your question!!!

Comment: sorry guys fixed it.

Comment: Related: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19684560/509868) to a more specific question

Comment: I can't withdraw my close vote, but it's no longer unclear. I'd say it is, however, a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7954439/827263).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the warning is on the `return`, in:

```
int istrlen(char *s)
{
  ...
  return p - s;
}
```

Then your compiler is being helpful... in this case, gcc will generate a warning if you ask for `-Wconversion`, because...

...the sum `p - s` is defined (C99 6.5.6), where both are pointers (to elements of the same array object, or to one past the last element of the same array object), to give a result of type `ptrdiff_t` -- which is a signed integer.  Now, on a typical 64-bit processor your `ptrdiff_t` will be a 64-bit signed integer, and your `int` is a 32-bit signed integer.  So, your compiler may be warning you that the conversion down from 64-bit to 32-bit signed integer, there could be an overflow.

You can write:

```
  return (int)(p - s) ;
```

to take responsibility for this, and the compiler will shrug and get on with its life.

[I'm slightly surprised that the warning is not given with straightforward `-Wall`... so this may not be the warning the question refers to.]

My second edition K&R is essentially C89, and also describes `ptrdiff_t` and its pal `size_t`.  I suspect the fragment of code you are looking at comes from a kinder, gentler age when `int` and `ptrdiff_t` were interchangeable (32-bit integers) -- or compilers were less keen to suggest that the programmer may not know what they are doing.  (Mind you, in 1989 a string longer than 2,147,483,647 characters was seriously unlikely !)

---

The other place where the compiler may be being helpful is at the:

```
  printf("%d\n", (sp+7) - s);
```

Where, again, the result of the subtraction is `ptrdiff_t`, but the `%d` expects an `int`.  This is a more serious problem, because the `%d` only knows how to eat an `int`, and may go wrong eating an `int`, especially where there are more arguments following it.

Comment: That statement doesn't produce the reported warning, and adding a cast would not be helpful. The linked screenshot shows the actual code and the warning that it produces. The code currently in the question is largely irrelevant. The question needs to be updated. (It would probably be better to change `istrlen` so it returns `size_t` rather than `int`.)

Comment: @KiethThompson... on my gcc, `-Wconversion` generates a warning: "conversion to 'int' from 'long int' may alter its value".  I confess, however, to being slightly surprised that `-Wall` and `-Wextra` are not sufficient !

Comment: I had rather assumed that it was the `return s - p ;` which was generating a warning.  Sorry.  On more mature reflection, and with further information, the warning in question is for the same reason, but in a more significant place... I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Subtraction of two pointers yields a result of type `ptrdiff_t`, which is a typedef (alias) for some implementation-defined signed integer type.

You have:

```
printf("%d\n", (sp+7) - s);
```

where the operands of the subtraction are both pointers of type `char*` (`s` is an array which decays to a pointer to its first element). The `"%d"` format requires an argument of type `int`. `ptrdiff_t` is apparently a typedef for `long` on your system.

To fix this, either cast the result (probably to `long`, but `int` should work):

```
printf("%ld\n", (long)((sp+7) - s));
```

or use the correct format string for `ptrdiff_t`:

```
printf("%td\n", (sp+7) - s);
```

Personally, I'd probably use the cast; I didn't remember that `t` is the length modifier for `ptrdiff_t` until I looked it up in the standard. (And pre-C99 implementations might not support `"%td"`.)

Passing `printf` an argument that's not of the correct type (after promotion) specified by the format string causes undefined behavior. As for why it happened to work, perhaps `int` and `long` happen to have the same size and representation in your implementation, or if `long` is wider than `int` perhaps `long` arguments are passed in such a way that when `printf` tries to grab an `int` value (probably off the stack) it happens to get the low-order `sizeof (int)` bytes of the `long` argument. That's the nature of undefined behavior; the *worst* thing that can happen is that it appears to work correctly. (That's bad because the code could fail unpredictably later on.)