# Where am I in my array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

**this is automatically generated C code, so please don't mind my method of scrolling though a char pointer**

I'm using a char pointer to store a string:

```
char str[] = "Hello!";
char *ptr = str;
```

And I use pointer arithmetic to scroll through it:

```
++ptr;
++ptr;
...
...
--ptr;
```

I'd like to know at some point to exactly what index it's pointing (eg. 1 for 'e' in "Hello"). How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Appropriately enough, `std::distance(str, ptr)` or just `ptr - str`.

Answer (score 2):

You can Simply print that corresponding value with printf or cout with %c to get the character where that is pointing.

```
printf("%c",*p);
```

If you want to know the position then

```
printf("%td\n",ptr-str);
```

Comment: the correct format is  [`%td`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954439/c-which-character-should-be-used-for-ptrdiff-t-in-printf), not `%d`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thank you I done that in editing. But normally use the %d it is working.

Comment: no, stricly speaking, it's undefined behavior, esp. in systems with pointers larger than 32 bits like 64-bit architectures

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
   printf("\ndistance[%d]",ptr-str);
```

Comment: the result of the subtraction between 2 pointers isn't an int, so using `%d` invoke undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, simplest way is use std::distance. This will return the number of elements between the given iterators. In your case, std::distance(str, ptr) return the number of elements between str and ptr. Say str is pointing to start and ptr is somewhere at 'o', then the value returned by this API is 4.