# Index of element pointed to by pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a 2D char array declared as

```
char A[100][100]
```

I also have a pointer that points to one element of that array

```
char *ptr;
ptr = A[5]
```

This pointer gets passed to another function, which needs to be able to know the index of that pointer (in this case, 5)

```
void func(void *ptr) {
int index = ???
}
```

How can I do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Why not just pass the index along: `void func(void *ptr, size_t i);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible if you can see `A` in `func` (A is just a doubly-indexed 1D array, not a pointer on arrays, that's why it is possible).

```
#include <stdio.h>

char A[100][100];

void func(void *ptr) {
  char *ptrc = (char*)ptr;
  printf("index %d\n",int((ptrc-A[0])/sizeof(A[0])));
}

int main()
{
  char *ptr = A[5];
  func(ptr);
}
```

result:

```
index 5
```

of course, if you pass an unrelated pointer to `func` you'll have undefined results.

Note: it is required to cast the incoming `void *` pointer to `char *` or the compiler won't let us diff pointers of incompatible types.

EDIT: as I was challenged by chqrlie to compute both indexes, I tried it and it worked (also added safety to prevent the function being called with an unrelated pointer):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

char A[100][100];

void func(void *ptr) 
{
  char *ptrc = (char*)ptr;
  ptrdiff_t diff = (ptrc-A[0]);
  assert(0 <= diff);
  assert(diff < sizeof(A));
  printf("index %d %d\n",(int)(diff/sizeof(A[0])),(int)(diff % sizeof(A[0])));
}

int main()
{
  char *ptr = &(A[5][34]);
  func(ptr);
}
```

result:

```
index 5 34
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you do that initial cast of char *ptrc = (char*) ptr;? Can you not just use ptr in that print statement?

Comment: I need the pointer to be of the same type, or the compiler won't let me diff the pointers.

Comment: The pointer could point *inside* the 2D array, computing both indices seems palatable.

Comment: @chqrlie it is indeed possible with another routine, see my edit.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: let's congratulate each other with up ticks ;-)

Comment: Using C there there is no need to cast here `char *ptrc = (char*)ptr;`.

Comment: For this `int diff` there is `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: And in any case `%d` is the wrong conversion specifier.

Comment: @alk I knew I was doing something wrong. Will edit. Is %p all right for pointer diffs?

Comment: `sizeof` evaluates to `size_t` which, as being unsigned, probably ranks higher then `ptrdiff_t`, so it would need to `%zu`.

Comment: Subtraction of two pointers evaluates to an integer value. `%p` is for pointers, but you probably know this ... ;-)

Comment: To be super save one also wants to add something like `assert(diff > 0);` before going to devide the `signed` by the `unsigned`.

Comment: added assert, but `%zu` doesn't work. It just prints `zu`.

Comment: The `printf` statement is incorrect: `diff / sizeof(A[0])` has the larger type of `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t`,  which may be larger than `int`. You should cast the operands as `(int)(diff / sizeof(A[0]))` or possibly use `%zu` and cast as `(size_t)diff / sizeof(A[0])`

Comment: okay but my gcc 4.9 does not accept `%zu`. and pointer diff should be %td as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954439/c-which-character-should-be-used-for-ptrdiff-t-in-printf

Comment: `gcc` is fine, but your C library (Microsoft?) is not C99 compliant: cast the operands as `(int)`.

Comment: Oops: `assert(0 <= diff < sizeof(A));`? Might do what you expect in Python, but not in C.

Comment: The equivalent for `zu` when using VC is `lu`.

Comment: fixed the assert part (too much python those days!!) and cast to int, else it would require to set some GNU define so gcc doesn't use windows printf. Not worth it IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the offset of `ptr` from the beginning of the array and derive the coordinates:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char A[100][100];

void func(void *ptr) {
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("ptr = NULL\n");
        return;
    }
    ptrdiff_t pos = (char *)ptr - A[0];
    if (pos < 0 || pos > (ptrdiff_t)sizeof(A)) {
        printf("ptr points outside A: ptr=%p, A=%p..%p\n",
               ptr, (void*)A, (void*)&A[100][100]);
    } else {
        printf("ptr = &A[%d][%d]\n",
               (int)((size_t)pos / sizeof(A[0])),  // row number
               (int)((size_t)pos % sizeof(A[0])))  // column number
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char *ptr = &A[5][3];
    func(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For this `size_t pos` there is `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @alk: That's correct, but `pos` is positive by constuction if `ptr` is a valid pointer inside `A` or at its upper edge. The conversion is fine in this case.  If `ptr` is `NULL` or points outside `A`, computing the difference is meaningless anyway.